# make an input only-numeric type on knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

i read many tutorials but i dont know how to do this, this is the input

```
input(type="text",name="price",id="price"data-bind="text: price,valueUpdate:['afterkeydown','propertychange','input']")
```

and this is my viewModel

```
price: ko.computed(function()
{
    return parseFloat(this.replace(' ','').replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")) || '';
},this)
```

but this cause error: this has no method replace??? how can i pass the price value to the computed function??

Comment: Instead of `input type="text"`, what if you change it to `input type="number"`? I think those limit what you put into them to only numeric values.

Comment: type="number" has less compatibility with some browsers

Comment: Jon is correct in that you can change type to number but if I remember correctly not all browsers support that type.  For example, I believe anything before IE10 let's you put text in there with no problems

Comment: this can be usefull to see compatibilites http://caniuse.com/#search=number

Comment: so i cant use type number cause i have to work for IE8+ and firefox too

Comment: There is a topic about this in knockout's documentation. You may need to create an extender. Their sample actually did what you require. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

Comment: tnx! i resolve the problem tnx to you @alpinescrambler

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Is better to create custom binding http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html which accept only allowed characters [0-9,.] as numeric representation.

put this line into your view

```
<input id="text" type="text" data-bind="numeric, value: number">
```

put this line into your model (remember to bind number as observable property)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numeric = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).on("keydown", function (event) {
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
            if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: . ,
                (event.keyCode == 188 || event.keyCode == 190 || event.keyCode == 110) ||
                // Allow: home, end, left, right
                (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            else {
                // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Does this really work? For me it doeesn't update Observable if it is somewhere on the UI? For example, you have <input ...> as above and also some <span data-bind="text: number"></span>. In this case, if user edits number inside input, UI is not updated after edit is done.

Comment: Changes will be apply after focus change from input field. Here is simple example with live edit (without focus change).

http://jsfiddle.net/jakethashi/L7UEm/

Comment: @renathy I left the textInput binding, and added the numeric as a second binding, works great

Comment: How do you handle the dutch keyboard ? where numbers are Shift + Key ?

Comment: Also the Czech keyboard does not work which also need Shift+number to work.

Comment: It also doesn't work for a French keyboard layout that uses Shift for entering numbers

Answer (score 9):

Knockout has extenders for this. [Check This](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) from knockoutjs.com explaining how to use observable extenders to force input to be numeric. I paste the code from the documentation here:

**Source code: View**

```
<p><input data-bind="value: myNumberOne" /> (round to whole number)</p>
<p><input data-bind="value: myNumberTwo" /> (round to two decimals)</p>
```

**Source code: View model**

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {
    //create a writable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
    var result = ko.pureComputed({
        read: target,  //always return the original observables value
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target(),
                roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
                newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(+newValue),
                valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

            //only write if it changed
            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                target(valueToWrite);
            } else {
                //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
                if (newValue !== current) {
                    target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

    //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
    result(target());

    //return the new computed observable
    return result;
};

function AppViewModel(one, two) {
    this.myNumberOne = ko.observable(one).extend({ numeric: 0 });
    this.myNumberTwo = ko.observable(two).extend({ numeric: 2 });
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(221.2234, 123.4525));
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem.

I also needed to ensure inter values only, and for IE9 and up (so type=numberical was not enough), and since we have a lot of international customers, i could not rely on keycodes either, so the following is what i ended up with:

```
//In my js class method (self is this as usual)
self.ensureNumberical = function (data, e) {
    var keyValue = e.key;
    if (keyValue.match(/[0-9]/g)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//In my MVC View
data-bind="event: { keypress: ensureNumberical }"
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach: I have found that Knockout works well in combination with [jQuery-validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). You just need to make sure that you validate the form before you attempt to use the numeric value.

Say you have a form DOM element, you can set up validation rules via

```
$(".yourform").validate({
    rules: {
        year: {
            digits: true,
            minlength: 4,
            maxlength: 4
        }
    },
    messages: {
        year: "Please enter four digits (e.g. 2009).",
    }
});
```

In your viewmodel you set the two-way binding up as usual, e.g. via `self.year = ko.observable("")`. Now make sure that you call `$(".yourform").valid()` before you are further processing `self.year()`. In my case, I am doing `var year = parseInt(self.year(), 10)`. Right after form validation this is expected to always produce a meaningful result.

Answer (score 2):

Best for today's scenerio  https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

run the snippet below. entering a non digit or something more than 255 will cause the message to display.

```js
function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.myObj = ko.observable().extend({ digit: true }).extend({ max: 255});
  }
  
  var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.validation.init();
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.min.js"></script>

enter a digit less than or equal to  255 <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: myObj">

<p>
  Enter something other than a digit or over 255 will cause an error.
</p>
```

courtesy: Bryan Dellinger: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42940109/3868653

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input type="text" id="alpha-validation" data-bind="value: YourDataName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown' , event: { 'input': AlphaCheck}" style="text-transform:uppercase">
```

create AlphaCheck Function and add that.

```
    $('#alpha-validation').keyup(function () {
        if (this.value.match(/[^0-9 ]/g)) {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9 ]/g, '');
        }
    });
```

**That will works!**

Answer (score 1):

We can restrict user to input user more than two decimal number Ex. 23.81, 3452.83 Modified code is as below. The reference code is taken from the @Martin Surynek answer.

HTML -

```
<p>
    <input data-bind="value: myNumberOne" /> (round to whole number)</p>
  <p>
    <input data-bind="num, value: myNumberTwo" /> (round to two decimals)</p>
```

Script -

```
<script>
    ko.bindingHandlers.num = {
      init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).on("keypress", function (event) {
          //debugger
          console.log(event.keyCode);
          var $this = $(this);
          var text = $this.val();

          // Stop insert two dots
          if ($this.val().indexOf('.') != -1 && (event.which == 190 || event.which == 110)) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }

          // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
          if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode ==
            13 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
            // Allow: .   ,event.keyCode == 188 ||
            ( event.keyCode == 190 || event.keyCode == 110) ||
            // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
          }

          // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
          if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode >
              105)) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }

          if ((event.which == 46) && (text.indexOf('.') == -1)) {
            setTimeout(function () {
              if ($this.val().substring($this.val().indexOf('.')).length > 3) {
                $this.val($this.val().substring(0, $this.val().indexOf('.') + 3));
              }
            }, 1);
          }

          if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) &&
            (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2) &&
            (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
            ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }          
          //console.log($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2);
        });
      }
    };


    ko.extenders.numeric = function (target, precision) {
      //create a writable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable

      var result = ko.pureComputed({
        read: target, //always return the original observables value
        write: function (newValue) {

          var current = target(),
            roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
            newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(+newValue),
            valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

          //only write if it changed
          if (valueToWrite !== current) {
            target(valueToWrite);
          } else {
            //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
            if (newValue !== current) {
              target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
            }
          }
        }
      }).extend({
        notify: 'always'
      });

      //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
      result(target());

      //return the new computed observable
      return result;
    };

    function AppViewModel(one, two) {
      this.myNumberOne = ko.observable(one).extend({
        numeric: 0
      });
      this.myNumberTwo = ko.observable(two).extend({
        numeric: 2
      });
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(221.2234, 123.4525));
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a year old but let me post this for the sake of feature visitor of the page.

Check this out:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numericnumbers = {
init: function (element) {
    $(element).on('keypress', function (number) {
        number = (number) ? number : window.event;
        var charcode = (number.which) ? number.which : number.keyCode;
        if (charcode > 31 && (charcode < 48 || charcode > 75))
            number.preventDefault();
    });
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create you data-bind pointing at your shiny new code:

```
<input id="price" name="price" type="text" data-bind="numeric">
```

Shiny new knockout code:

```
price = ko.observable();
price.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    price = newValue.replace(/[\D\.]/g, '');
});
```

This means that every time you update the price, it will apply the logic in the function (in this case stripping out anything that isn't a number or a period), and apply it directly to the price. You can also add other validation or cool features here, like adding a currency sybmol at the start, keeping it to 2 decimal places, etc...

Answer (score 0):

With the help of "keydown" event we can restrict other key's in text box which should hold numeric values.

```
$(document).ready(function(){                
        $("selector").on("keydown", function (e) {
            //numbers, delete, backspace, arrows
            var validKeyCodes = [8, 9, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57];
            if (!($.inArray(e.keyCode, validKeyCodes) >= 0))
                    e.preventDefault();                 
        });           
    });
```