# Converting circular structure to JSON in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mvc, knockout-3.0

I have two grid structure, In one of them I have multiple fields multiple times, whereas, in one I have two fields single time. I write apply method for each grid my first grid id working fine, but when I am clicking apply on second grid I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Here are both the apply methods:

```
self.applyRate = function (loan) {
    //  commit the edit transaction
    self.editTransaction.notifySubscribers(null, "commit");
    alert(ko.toJSON({data:loan}));
    //  hides the edit fields
    self.editingItem(null);
};
   self.apply = function (data) {
    //  commit the edit transaction
    self.editTransaction.notifySubscribers(null, "commit");
    alert(ko.toJSON({data:data}));
    self.editingItem(null);
};
```

`applyRate()` calls when I click on edit, and click the apply on first grid, i.e, loan.

I am getting problem while clicking apply for mandatory and benefits text field.

Here is a Js Fiddle Link: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sohimohit/3L58kvwh/)

Comment: What is reason to bind `$root` here `$root.applyRate.bind($root)`?

Comment: Knockout uses JSON.stringify under the hood.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392293/stringify-javascript-object-with-circular-reference for the solution