# fire onchange event on textbox using knockout

Tags: knockout.js

here am working on a snippet to get the calculations done using knockout and attached is the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/naren_net/55etxj4y/272/

```js
var vm = function() {
  this.PrevActualQty = ko.observable();
  this.PrevUnitCost = ko.observable();
  this.PrevTotalCost = ko.observable();

  this.ChangeQty = ko.observable(0);
  this.ChangeUnitCost = ko.observable(0);
  this.ChangeTotalCost = ko.observable(0);

  this.NewActualTotalCost = ko.observable(0);



  this.PrevTotalCost = ko.computed(function() {
    return (isNaN(this.PrevActualQty() * this.PrevUnitCost()) ? "" : this.PrevActualQty() * this.PrevUnitCost());
  }, this);

  this.NewActualQty = ko.computed(function() {
    return ((isNaN(this.PrevActualQty()) ? 0 : Number(this.PrevActualQty())) + (isNaN(this.ChangeQty()) ? 0 : Number(this.ChangeQty())));
  }, this);

  this.NewActualUnitCost = ko.computed(function() {
    return (isNaN(this.PrevUnitCost()) ? 0 : Number(this.PrevUnitCost()) + (isNaN(this.ChangeUnitCost()) ? 0 : Number(this.ChangeUnitCost())));
  }, this);

  this.NewActualTotalCost = ko.computed(function() {
    return (isNaN(this.NewActualQty()) ? 0 : Number(this.NewActualQty()) * (isNaN(this.NewActualUnitCost()) ? 0 : Number(this.NewActualUnitCost())));
  }, this);

  this.ChangeTotalCost = ko.computed(function() {
    return ((this.NewActualTotalCost()) - (this.PrevTotalCost()));
  }, this);

  this.ChangeTotalCost.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert(newValue);
  });

  this.Changed = function() {
    alert("fired");
    this.NewActualTotalCost(this.ChangeTotalCost() + this.PrevTotalCost());
  }
}


ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <th>
    <td align=center>Qty</td>
    <td align=center>Unit Cost</td>
    <td align=center>Total Cost</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>Prev Actual</td>
    <td><input type=textbox data-bind='value:PrevActualQty' style='text-align:right'></td>
    <td><input type=textbox data-bind='value:PrevUnitCost' style='text-align:right'></td>
    <td><input type=textbox data-bind='value:PrevTotalCost()' style='text-align:right'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Actual</td>
    <td align=right><input type=textbox data-bind='value:ChangeQty' style='text-align:right'></td>
    <td align=right><input type=textbox data-bind='value:ChangeUnitCost' style="text-align:right"></td>
    <td align=right><input type=textbox data-bind="value:ChangeTotalCost, event:{onchange:Changed}" , style="text-align:right"></td>

    <td><span data-bind="text:ChangeTotalCost"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>New Actual</td>
    <td align=right><span data-bind="text:NewActualQty"></span></td>
    <td align=right><span data-bind="text:NewActualUnitCost"></span></td>
    <td align=right><span data-bind="text:NewActualTotalCost"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

the issue is the onchange on the textbox with value:ChangeTotalCost doesnt fire. 
i want to capture the updated value and recalculate the value of NewActualTotalCost. is something wrong with the approach?

Thanks!

---

Thanks for the response!
Actual is current data row that user can update, when user updates any of New Actual Row i.e Actual Qty / Actual Unit Cost / Actual Total Cost that should calculate the New Actual row data.
all the three are computables, first 2 work fine, but the third(ChangeTotalCost) should update the NewActualTotalCost with PrevTotalCost + NewActualTotalCost and that should calculate the ActualUnitCost as (NewActualTotalCost /NewActualQty) - PrevActualUnitCost

Answer (score 0):

When knockout updates an input, there's no `change` event. Those events are only trigered by user interaction.

When working with `<input>` elements and knockout, you usually don't bind to a `change` event at all; you `subscribe` to the data-bound value instead!

Unfortunately, you'd create a circular dependency by doing so:

1. `ChangeTotalCost` relies on `NewActualTotalCost`
2. When `ChangeTotalCost` changes, you want the `Changed` method to update `NewActualTotalCost`
3. Go back to 1, because a dependency changed

It's not entirely clear to me what your intended logic should be. If you can clarify the relation between the rows, I can help look for an alternative to the faulty event-based approach.

Comment: I'm afraid your explanation doesn't make it any clearer for me. Might be nice to start out by a) removing all duplicate property declarations , b) making the computed inputs `readonly`, and c) replacing the `Number` parsing logic by a [numeric extender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30371515/3297291) to make things a bit more readable.