# Update observable when input value changes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a input group with a field called 'hours', this field can be changed either using -/+ buttons on each side of the field, or by manually typing in the field.

When using the -/+ button the value is updated correctly, but I cannot get it to update when the user types in the value manually in the input box.

Due to the setup I cant use subscribe, since that is triggered when the buttons change the values too. Is there some way I can solve this?

Code (functions 'subHours' and 'addHours' just adds -/+ 1 to the current value):

```
<div class="input-group">\
    <span class="input-group-btn">\
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: subHours">\
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>\
           </button>\
    </span><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: hours"/>\
    <span class="input-group-btn">\
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: addHours">\
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>\
           </button>\
    </span>\
</div>\
```

I would like to call a function in a similar way to when a button is clicked.

Comment: It would be easier if you just showed the current JS code..

Comment: @Ray what current JS code? The functions that get called when pressing the buttons? Because that is the only JS code that is related to this. And a simple observable called 'hours'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number input box in Knockout JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394445/number-input-box-in-knockout-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be updating correctly, as seen from the `ko.toJSON()`.

```js
var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  this.hours = ko.observable(0);
  this.subHours = function(){
    self.hours(self.hours()-1);
  };
  this.addHours = function(){
    self.hours(self.hours()+1);
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-field="week.id" data-bind="click: subHours">Sub
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
           </button>
    </span><input type="text" name="week.id" class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: hours"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-field="week.id" data-bind="click: addHours">Add
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
           </button>
    </span>
</div>


<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(hours)"></span>
```

Comment: Hmm, clicking "Run code snippet" I get the same behaviour I'm getting in my solution. i.e sometimes it's treated as a string. Try manually adding numbers to the field then clicking -/+ buttons.

Comment: Yes, that is how it's intended to work. If you want to ensure that it's always numeric you need to use extenders or custom bindings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048468/make-an-input-only-numeric-type-on-knockout,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394445/number-input-box-in-knockout-js